# how to make complex shapes using swarm of dots......like chair,rocket and many more using pygame and numpy

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, pygame, pickle

i am working on a project of swarm algorithms and i am trying to make complex shapes using the swarm consensus. However, the mathematics to achieve that seems quite difficult for me.

I have been able to make shapes like stars, circle and triangle but to make other complex shapes seems more harder. It would be very helpful if i get the idea of using numpy arrays to build these complex shapes using swarms....................................................

```py
    # general function to reset radian angle to [-pi, pi)
    def reset_radian(radian):
        while radian >= math.pi:
            radian = radian - 2*math.pi
        while radian < -math.pi:
            radian = radian + 2*math.pi
        return radian



    # general function to calculate next position node along a heading direction
    def cal_next_node(node_poses, index_curr, heading_angle, rep_times):
        for _ in range(rep_times):
            index_next = index_curr + 1
            x = node_poses[index_curr][0] + 1.0*math.cos(heading_angle)
            y = node_poses[index_curr][1] + 1.0*math.sin(heading_angle)
            node_poses[index_next] = np.array([x,y])
            index_curr = index_next
        return index_next


    ##### script to generate star #####
    filename = 'star'
    swarm_size = 30
    node_poses = np.zeros((swarm_size, 2))
    outer_angle = 2*math.pi / 5.0
    devia_right = outer_angle
    devia_left = 2*outer_angle
    # first node is at bottom left corner
    heading_angle = outer_angle / 2.0  # current heading
    heading_dir = 0  # current heading direction: 0 for left, 1 for right
    seg_count = 0  # current segment count
    for i in range(1,swarm_size):
        node_poses[i] = (node_poses[i-1] +
            np.array([math.cos(heading_angle), math.sin(heading_angle)]))
        seg_count = seg_count + 1
        if seg_count == 3:
            seg_count = 0
            if heading_dir == 0:
                heading_angle = reset_radian(heading_angle - devia_right)
                heading_dir = 1
            else:
                heading_angle = reset_radian(heading_angle + devia_left)
                heading_dir = 0
    print(node_poses)
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        pickle.dump(node_poses, f)

    pygame.init()
    # find the right world and screen sizes
    x_max, y_max = np.max(node_poses, axis=0)
    x_min, y_min = np.min(node_poses, axis=0)
    pixel_per_length = 30
    world_size = (x_max - x_min + 2.0, y_max - y_min + 2.0)
    screen_size = (int(world_size[0])*pixel_per_length, int(world_size[1])*pixel_per_length)
    # convert node poses in the world to disp poses on screen
    def cal_disp_poses():
        poses_temp = np.zeros((swarm_size, 2))
        # shift the loop to the middle of the world
        middle = np.array([(x_max+x_min)/2.0, (y_max+y_min)/2.0])
        for i in range(swarm_size):
            poses_temp[i] = (node_poses[i] - middle +
                np.array([world_size[0]/2.0, world_size[1]/2.0]))
        # convert to display coordinates
        poses_temp[:,0] = poses_temp[:,0] / world_size[0]
        poses_temp[:,0] = poses_temp[:,0] * screen_size[0]
        poses_temp[:,1] = poses_temp[:,1] / world_size[1]
        poses_temp[:,1] = 1.0 - poses_temp[:,1]
        poses_temp[:,1] = poses_temp[:,1] * screen_size[1]
        return poses_temp.astype(int)
    disp_poses = cal_disp_poses()

    # draw the loop shape on pygame window
    color_white = (255,255,255)
    color_black = (0,0,0)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size)
    screen.fill(color_white)
    for i in range(swarm_size):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, color_black, disp_poses[i], 5, 0)
    for i in range(swarm_size-1):
        pygame.draw.line(screen, color_black, disp_poses[i], disp_poses[i+1],2)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, color_black, disp_poses[0], disp_poses[swarm_size-1], 2)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your method for drawing takes huge advantage of the symmetries in the shapes you are drawing.  More complex shapes will have fewer symmetries and so your method will require a lot of tedious work to get them drawn with stars.  Without symmetry you may be better served writing each individual line 'command' in a list and following that list.  For example, drawing the number 4 starting from the bottom (assuming 0 degrees is --> that way):

```
angles = [90,225,0]
distances = [20,15,12]
```

Then with a similar program to what you have, you can start drawing dots in a line at 90 degrees for 20 dots, then 225 degrees for 15 dots etc...  Then by adding to these two lists you can build up a very complicated shape without relying on symmetry.